# Get a count of relationships connected to each node - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

please I want to get the **count of relationships (no_of_relationships)** connected to each node in a path.

```
MATCH (parent:Members {id:"1", position:"R"})-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
WHERE no_of_relationship < 1
```

So, I want to get all the nodes in this path where **no_of_relationship** is < 1

My question is how do I get **no_of_relationship**

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem

```
MATCH (parent:Members {id:"1"})-[:PARENT_OF*1..]->(c) 
WITH c as result
WHERE size((result)-->()) < 2
RETURN result.id, size((result)-->()) as no_of_relationship LIMIT 50
```

Thanks guys.